# split one column into two columns based on it's value using t/sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, query

Hope you're doing well.
I have a table as you can see below :

```
ACNTHEADER(DDATE DATE ,ACNTCODE INT,VALUE NUMERIC(17,2))
```

the data in the table :

```
DDATE       ACNTCODE     VALUE 
6/1/2013      1174       10.00
6/1/2013      1174       20.00
6/1/2013      1174       -3.00
6/5/2013      1174       -5.00
6/7/2013      1174       -1.00
6/8/2013      1174       -1.00
6/8/2013      1174       -1.00
6/8/2013      1174       -5.00
6/10/2013     1174        3.00
6/10/2013     1174       -3.00
```

I need to have blocks of data for each 'DATE' and the result should be like this :

```
DATE        ACNTCODE       SUMPOSITIVE   SUMNEGATIVE
6/1/2013      1174            30.00         -3.00
6/2/2013      1174              0              0
6/3/2013      1174              0              0
6/4/2013      1174              0              0
6/5/2013      1174              0           -5.00
6/6/2013      1174              0              0
6/7/2013      1174              0           -1.00
6/8/2013      1174              0           -7.00
6/9/2013      1174              0              0
6/10/2013     1174            +3.00         -3.00
```

I do not know how to split column `value` into two columns based on their value and another thing is that the way I'm building blocks of data is that I', joining my tables with `date` table in our database which is standard date table . I want to know whether there are better ways to do that.
this my query so far:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         D.MDATE ,
         A.ACNTCODE ,
         sum(CASE WHEN A.VALUE > 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS POSITIVEE,
         sum(CASE WHEN A.VALUE < 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS NEGATIVE       
  FROM ACNTHEADER A INNER JOIN DIMDATE D
      ON D.MDATE >= A.DDATE AND D.MDATE <= (SELECT MAX(B.DDATE)
                                    FROM ACNTHEADER B
                                    WHERE B.ACNTCODE = A.ACNTCODE)
  group by  D.MDATE ,
      A.ACNTCODE 
  ORDER BY D.MDATE
```

I have just edited my query. The problem now is that for those dates that are not in the `ACNTHEADER`table I need to have zero value but the final result is not correct with my query . How to I handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the right track just a few things to keep in mind.

1. Make a left join to the date table (DIMDATE).

`FROM DIMDATE D  LEFT JOIN ACNTHEADER A`

Which make sure that no days are omitted.

2. Since you are trying to add the values based on date, you need an Aggregate function in the final columns.`SUM` in your case.
3. To split the columns based on the value you can use the below.

`SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE>0 THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS SUMPOSITIVE`

Try it and see if face any roadblocks if any Please comment.

**ANSWER**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ACNTHEADER') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ACNTHEADER

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DIMDATE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DIMDATE


CREATE TABLE #ACNTHEADER
(DDATE DATE,
 ACNTCODE INT,
 VALUE NUMERIC(17,2))


 CREATE TABLE #DIMDATE(
 MDATE DATE
 )


INSERT INTO #ACNTHEADER
SELECT '20130601',      1174,       10.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130601',      1174,       20.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130601',      1174,       -3.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130605',      1174,       -5.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130607',      1174,       -1.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130608',      1174,       -1.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130608',      1174,       -1.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130608',      1174,       -5.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130610',      1174,        3.00  UNION ALL
SELECT '20130610',      1174 ,      -3.00


INSERT INTO #DIMDATE
select TOP 30 DATEADD (day,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1,'20130601')
FROM sys.tables,sys.columns




SELECT MDATE,
       CR.ACNTCODE,
       ISNULL(POSITIVEE,0)POSITIVEE,
       ISNULL(NEGATIVE,0)NEGATIVE    
  FROM #DIMDATE D 
  CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT DISTINCT ACNTCODE
              FROM #ACNTHEADER
              )CR
  LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT A.ddate ,
               A.ACNTCODE ,
               SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE > 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS POSITIVEE,
               SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE < 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS NEGATIVE    
          FROM #ACNTHEADER A 
         GROUP BY A.ddate,
               A.ACNTCODE) AD on ad.DDATE = D.MDATE 
                        AND cr.ACNTCODE = ad.ACNTCODE
```

I hope your date filter condition is correct, so I am not editing it.

**Explanation**

1. Use of `LEFT JOIN`

   This is to make sure that you need all the values for June month for 2013.
   If you do an `INNER JOIN` it will only show the values in matching in both 
   table.
2. Doing Pre-Aggregation before doing a `LEFT JOIN`

   For the first answer, I posted was getting duplicated records. I was in the pre-assumption that the date was joined multiple times and I was wrong.The best way to understand this is by comparing both the result set. Sometimes it hard to visualize so break down your query and see how the `JOIN` works.

**First Answer**

```
    SELECT D.MDATE ,
           A.ACNTCODE ,
           SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE > 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS POSITIVEE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE < 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS NEGATIVE

      FROM #DIMDATE D 
      LEFT JOIN 
           #ACNTHEADER A 
           ON D.MDATE >= A.DDATE AND D.MDATE <= (SELECT MAX(B.DDATE)
                                FROM #ACNTHEADER B
                                WHERE B.ACNTCODE = A.ACNTCODE)
     GROUP BY  D.MDATE,
           A.ACNTCODE 
      ORDER BY D.MDATE
```

before this will check the one without the filtering clause on this one.

```
    SELECT D.MDATE ,
           A.ACNTCODE ,
           SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE > 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS POSITIVEE,
           SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE < 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS NEGATIVE

      FROM #DIMDATE D 
      LEFT JOIN 
           #ACNTHEADER A 
           ON D.MDATE = A.DDATE 
     GROUP BY  D.MDATE,
           A.ACNTCODE 
      ORDER BY D.MDATE
```

╔════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║   MDATE    ║ ACNTCODE ║ POSITIVEE ║ NEGATIVE ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2013-06-01 ║ 1174     ║     30.00 ║    -3.00 ║
║ 2013-06-02 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-03 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-04 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-05 ║ 1174     ║      0.00 ║    -5.00 ║
║ 2013-06-06 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-07 ║ 1174     ║      0.00 ║    -1.00 ║
║ 2013-06-08 ║ 1174     ║      0.00 ║    -7.00 ║
║ 2013-06-09 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-10 ║ 1174     ║      3.00 ║    -3.00 ║
║ 2013-06-11 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-12 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-13 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-14 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-15 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-16 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-17 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-18 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-19 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-20 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-21 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-22 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-23 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-24 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-25 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-26 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-27 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-28 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-29 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
║ 2013-06-30 ║ NULL     ║      0.00 ║     0.00 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝

In which we are getting the expected result set, One thing to note is the account was not shown on all rows but only on the valid dates on the right-hand table (#ACNTHEADER) and the requirement is to show account in all rows.

3. How to make the account duplicate for each row in table A (DIMDATE).
   For this, we use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT MDATE,
       CR.ACNTCODE

  FROM #DIMDATE D 
  CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT DISTINCT ACNTCODE
              FROM #ACNTHEADER
              )CR
```

╔════════════╦══════════╗
║   MDATE    ║ ACNTCODE ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2013-06-01 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-02 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-03 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-04 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-05 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-06 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-07 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-08 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-09 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-10 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-11 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-12 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-13 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-14 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-15 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-16 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-17 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-18 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-19 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-20 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-21 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-22 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-23 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-24 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-25 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-26 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-27 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-28 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-29 ║     1174 ║
║ 2013-06-30 ║     1174 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝

Why I used `DISTINCT` in `SUB QUERY` for `CROSS JOIN` is to minimize the rows to process. As it can lead to multiplying the rows based on the number of rows in each table. if `DISTINCT` is not used this will lead to wrong results as it will have duplicates. Also, be careful when doing `CROSS JOIN` as it can be a resource consuming process.

Now all we have to do the aggregation on the value that matches with the value in `#ACNTHEADER` for which we use a `LEFT JOIN`
on the `#ACNTHEADER` table

```
SELECT MDATE,
       CR.ACNTCODE,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE > 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END),0) POSITIVE ,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.VALUE < 0 THEN A.VALUE ELSE 0 END) ,0) NEGATIVE

  FROM #DIMDATE D 
  CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT DISTINCT ACNTCODE
              FROM #ACNTHEADER
              )CR
  LEFT JOIN

           #ACNTHEADER A ON a.ACNTCODE = cr.ACNTCODE 
                       AND d.MDATE= a.DDATE
         GROUP BY  MDATE,
       CR.ACNTCODE
```

Which is the required result set. Now, what went wrong on the first query. Even the pre-aggregation is not required! And all this was because of the filter clause on `DATE` value which resulted in duplicates.

```
D.MDATE >= A.DDATE AND D.MDATE <= (SELECT MAX(B.DDATE)
                                FROM #ACNTHEADER B
                                WHERE B.ACNTCODE = A.ACNTCODE)
```

I am leaving this to the reader to see how the filter works by running the query for one row and see how its getting changed which will be a good exercise for you analyzing SQL code.

**NB** Also, note I have only considered the June month for 2013, change `dimdate` table according to your need.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you need to compile a list of dates, and optionally, list of possible codes (your question specified only one, but including all to pick from is trivial), group by possible date and possible code, then left join to the data entries to pick out positive and negative values to sum. Expressed as a single query (so, no procedural logic), this can be done like so:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DDATE = MIN(DDATE), TARGETDATE = MAX(DDATE)
    FROM ACNTHEADER
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DDATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DDATE), TARGETDATE
    FROM dates
    WHERE DDATE < TARGETDATE
)
SELECT
    DATE = dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE,
    SUMPOSITIVE = SUM(CASE WHEN ent.VALUE > 0 THEN ent.VALUE ELSE 0 END),
    SUMNEGATIVE = SUM(CASE WHEN ent.VALUE < 0 THEN ent.VALUE ELSE 0 END)
FROM dates
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACNTCODE
    FROM ACNTHEADER
) codes
LEFT JOIN ACNTHEADER ent
ON ent.DDATE = dates.DDATE AND ent.ACNTCODE = codes.ACNTCODE
GROUP BY dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE
ORDER BY dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

In practice, if you have a lot of data, you may need to break this down slightly, computing the list of dates separately:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE, @MaxDate DATE;
SELECT @MinDate = MIN(DDATE), @MaxDate = MAX(DDATE)
FROM ACNTHEADER;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#Dates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Dates;
CREATE TABLE #Dates (DDATE DATE PRIMARY KEY);
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DDATE = @MinDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DDATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DDATE)
    FROM dates
    WHERE DDATE < @MaxDate
)
INSERT INTO #Dates
SELECT *
FROM dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SELECT
    DATE = dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE,
    SUMPOSITIVE = SUM(CASE WHEN ent.VALUE > 0 THEN ent.VALUE ELSE 0 END),
    SUMNEGATIVE = SUM(CASE WHEN ent.VALUE < 0 THEN ent.VALUE ELSE 0 END)
FROM #Dates dates
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACNTCODE
    FROM ACNTHEADER
) codes
LEFT JOIN ACNTHEADER ent
ON ent.DDATE = dates.DDATE AND ent.ACNTCODE = codes.ACNTCODE
GROUP BY dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE
ORDER BY dates.DDATE, codes.ACNTCODE;
```

Personally I'd go for the single query option unless breaking it down is really needed however.